# Please set JAVA_HOME to a Java 1.5 JDK Install / WEBGOAT

Tags: software-installation, java, jdk, openjdk

i am total noob starting to work with ubuntu.
I am trying to set up Ubuntu Server with Webgoat 5.4.
I downloaded the file "Webgoat-5.4-OWASP_Standard_Win32.zip" and tried to run the "webgoat.sh" with the command

```
sudo sh webgoat.sh start8080
```

, but i receive the result: "Please set Java_Home to a Java 1.5 JDK Install".

I am trying to Install Java 1.5 but none of the comments on the Internet are working for me.

With the command :

```
ls /usr/lib/jvm/
```

I receive the output: default-java, java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64, java-8-openjdk-amd64.

I am wondering how I can Install Java 5 in this specific folder.

Furthermore I need to edit the file webgoat.sh and I am wondering if this code will work with Java 5 to start Webgoat:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/Java-1-5-0.sun
```

Moreover I am wondering whether someone knows how to make webgoat accessable from the Internet. I would be happy about some advice because I am strugglin with this problem, too.

I hope you guys can help me out.

Comment: Decide which issue you want resolved: java_home path, install java or install webgoat!

Comment: Well I Want to get Webgoat Working and hence I Need to install Java 1.5 and set Java_Home to a Java 1.5.

Comment: why are you using java 5 and not java 8 or 9?

Comment: I am using "java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64" , but I need to set it to 5 to get Webgoat working.

Comment: your ubuntu version?

Comment: https://www.ubuntu.com/download/server  -- 16.04.2

Comment: Do you need the version that has _developer labs_ samples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of, you are trying to install an version of `Webgoat` and the `java` you have is ok to run it. Now these are the steps are followed to install it:

1. Place `java` in your path so `Webgoat` would see it.

   - open your `.bashrc` file:

     - In the terminal edit the `.bashrc` file with `nano /home/$USER/.bashrc`
     - Add the following lines to the file:

       ```
       export JAVA_PATH="/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64"
       export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME
       ```
     - Run this from terminal: `source ~/.bashrc`
2. Download `Webgoat` from [here](https://github.com/WebGoat/WebGoat-Legacy/wiki/Installation-(WebGoat-6.0)), select the **Quick Start - easy run** option. The link is in step two.
3. Run `Webgoat` with the following commands:

   ```
   java -jar WebGoat-6.0.1-war-exec.jar

   java -jar WebGoat-6.0.1-war-exec.jar -httpPort 9090
   ```

   - Please note: **first command runs on port 8080, and second command on port 9090**. Which of course you can change to any port of your liking.
   - When you run either of these, the terminal will spit out lots of error messages please ignore and run `step 4`.
4. Verify `Webgoat` is running:

   ```
   http://localhost:8080/WebGoat

   # or if using second command

   http://localhost:9090/WebGoat
   ```

Information:

> **WARNING 1**: While running this program your machine will be extremely vulnerable to attack. You should to disconnect from the Internet while using this program.
>
> **WARNING 2**: This program is for educational purposes only. If you attempt these techniques without authorization, you are very likely to get caught. If you are caught engaging in unauthorized hacking, most companies will fire you. Claiming that you were doing security research will not work as that is the first thing that all hackers claim.

Source:

https://github.com/WebGoat/WebGoat-Legacy

https://github.com/WebGoat/WebGoat-Legacy/wiki/Installation-(WebGoat-6.0)